# Angular expression not evaluating for text/ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here's the sample http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWrNGW.

```
<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="save-dialog.tmpl.html">
      <md-dialog>{{message}}</md-dialog>
    </script>
    <md-button ng-click="showDialog()">
      Show Dialog</md-button>
  </body>
```

Controller

angular.module('playground', ['ngMaterial'])

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showDialog = function() {
    $mdDialog.show({templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html'})
  };
  $scope.message = 'This message should idsplay on dialog';
});
```

Angular expression for {{message}} doesn't evaluate for text/ng-template on click of "Show Dialog" button even though its defined in the scope.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure the scope to inherit from, otherwise [$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) service will create a new isolated scope and of course there will be no `message` property.

Correct code in your case:

```
$mdDialog.show({
  templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html',
  scope: $scope
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scope to the opening of the dialog:

```
$mdDialog.show({
  templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html',
  scope: $scope
})
```